# Store question drafts in more than one site

Tags: feature-request, android-app, draft

Whenever I report a bug for the app or when having multiple questions on multiple SE sites, there is a 20 minute wait time between questions. This is expected to prevent too many sudden questions.

When I go to write a new question, post it, and I find this notification I know that I can back out and resume the question at a later time.

The problem I have is that when I am working across multiple SE sites and only limited to one question I have to write down my questions to post later because I can't draft them all on the SE app.

Feature Request - Is it possible to allow one of two things:

1. Allow drafting multiple questions and be able to resume any of them at a future time for post (such that I can format them as I would expect)
2. Separate the stored questions for each SE website